# How can I find this integral for a fourier series?

Tags: integration, fourier-series

I have to calculate the following integral $$ b_n = \dfrac{1}{\pi} \int_{-\pi}^{\pi} \dfrac{1}{2}x \sin nx dx$$

The correct answer is apparently $$\dfrac{(-1)^{n-1}}{n}$$

But I have no idea how I should get this answer. I was able to find that $$\int \dfrac{1}{2}x\sin nx dx = \dfrac{\sin nx - nx \cos nx}{2n^2}$$

How should I proceed?

Comment: Assuming what you did is correct, evaluate the last expression at $\pi$ and subtract by its evaluation at $-\pi$.

Comment: Your integral is between $\pi$ and $-\pi$ so you should substitute those for $x$ into the integral you've found.  Now think about $\cos n\pi$ and $\sin n\pi$ for integral $n$ -- when are they 0, -1 or +1?

Comment: $\cos(n\pi) = \cos(-n\pi)$ so those two are equal, but since you have $x$ attached, you get $\pi - -\pi =2\pi\cos(n\pi)$.  Think about $\cos(n\pi)$, it's either $+1$ when $n$ is even or $-1$ when $n$ is odd.

Comment: @Jared I get it, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

\begin{eqnarray*}
f(\alpha ) &=&\frac{1}{2\pi }\int_{-\pi }^{+\pi }dxx\sin (\alpha x)=-\frac{1%
}{2\pi }\partial _{\alpha }\int_{-\pi }^{+\pi }dx\cos (\alpha x)=-\frac{1}{%
2\pi }\partial _{\alpha }\left( \frac{\sin (\alpha x)}{\alpha }\right)
_{x=-\pi }^{+\pi } \\
&=&-\frac{1}{2\pi }\partial _{\alpha }\left( \frac{\sin (\alpha \pi )}{%
\alpha }-\frac{\sin (-\alpha \pi )}{\alpha }\right)\newline&=&-\frac{1}{\pi }\partial
_{\alpha }\left( \frac{\sin (\alpha \pi )}{\alpha }\right) =\frac{1}{\pi }%
\left( \frac{\sin (\alpha \pi )}{\alpha ^{2}}-\pi \frac{\cos (\alpha \pi )}{%
\alpha }\right)
\end{eqnarray*}
$$
b_{n}=f(n)=-\frac{\cos (n\pi )}{n}=(-1)^{n-1}\frac{1}{n}
$$